# How to create shortcut on ubuntu to open a terminal with some folder?

Tags: command-line, shortcuts

I have a ubuntu running in vmware, and the folder is mnt/hgfs/somefolder (shared folder from VMWARE).

How can i create a shortcut to open a terminal with this path (mnt/hgfs/somefolder) without need to type everytime cd mnt/hgfs/somefolder?

on windows I use a file somefile.bat with this code:

```
@cd /d "z:\somefolder\subfolder" 
@cmd.exe /K
```

It is possible to add some arguments to open in root mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command to open a terminal in a specific folder is

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/folder
```

One can create a `.desktop` file containing the following details to have a shortcut for this,

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyTerminal
Comment=open terminal in /mnt/hgfs/somefolder
Icon=utilities-terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal --working-directory=/mnt/hgfs/somefolder
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Give it execution permission, as

```
chmod +x /path/to/MyTerminal.desktop
```

It will create a shortcut named `MyTerminal`, now double click on it to open a terminal in your desired location.

Comment: To be root at that location use `sudo su` in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Open the `.bashrc` file ,

```
gedit .bashrc
```

Add the below line at the bottom of the file and then save it,

```
cd /mnt/hgfs/somefolder
```

Then source the `.bashrc` file to work,

```
source .bashrc
```

Now whenever you open the terminal,it directly `cd`(goes) into the `/mnt/hgfs/somefolder` directory.